# Does the root of var(a) to the power of var(n) all to the power of var(m) always equal var(a) to the power of var(n)-1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got this formula stating

$a^{(n+\frac 1n)}$ which yields $(a^{\frac1n})^{(n+1)}$

For the variables $a=25, n=2, m=3$ the formula gives the result $125$, which is equal to $a^n = 125$.

I understand that math flow, but I was wondering why it doesn't hold true for every $a,n,n+1$.

Comment: `m=3` What is $m\,$? `which is equal to a^n = 125` $25^2 \ne 125\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I'm sorry, but I honestly don't understand that syntax. Meant to place a newLine. Sorry about the initial problem being worded incorrectly. I will update the question, as I worded it wrong.

Comment: What we don't understand is why you are talking about $m$ when there is no $m$ in the equation you are discussing.

Comment: The m was originally in the equation, missed it when I noticed that m was just n+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^{(n+ \frac1n)} \ne \left(a^{\frac1n}\right)^{n+1}$$

Two of the laws of exponentiation are
$$a^{b+c} = a^ba^c$$and $$a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$$
So $$\left(a^{\frac1n}\right)^{n+1} = a^{\frac1n(n+1)}$$

But $$\frac1n(n+1) = \frac nn + \frac 1n = 1 + \frac 1n \ne n + \frac 1n$$

Comment: I went back and saw where I went wrong, came back a bit late, but thank you for the explanation. Minor mistake in the code I wrote to analyze my theory mainly...